Zip error: could not find end of central directory signature
I'm trying to decrypt a plain text (Plain text attack) that's in a zipped file.
I have all the files in my Downloads: backup.zip and my created slots_plain.txt that has exactly the same content as that of the slots.txt inside the zipped folder which is also locked.
What can you suggest?
The backup.zip is intact since everyone used it successfully. I downloaded that several times. Still the same.
On Homebrew:
(base) loyowens@MBP Downloads % bkcrack -C backup.zip -c slots.txt -P slots_plain.txt -p slots_plain.txt
I tried in Win11. It was about to give the keys. A pop up appeared sayingthe app (bkcrack.exe) will nnot run in my computer, contact publisher for version. Insane! After running for awhile. I checked security settings, app settings, all clear. So now back to home brew MAC OS

There could be a number of things preventing you from reading the zip file. Can you share a link to the file?
